# What is the difference between html <var> and <p 'font-style: italic'></p>?

Tags: html, tags

I tried to search the web about what is the purpose of the HTML `<var>` Tag and didn't find any good explanation or let say I'm not satisfied yet.  I can read what they say about it but I don't understand the purpose.  I tried two different lines of code and both gives me the same thing now I need to know what exactly is `<var>` and why we should use it rather than a single style.

```
<var>y</var> = <var>m</var><var>x</var> + <var>b</var>
<p style='font-style:italic'>y = mx + b</p>
```

Reference to name only one: https://html.com/tags/var/

Funny because I read the explanation but I still don't see what is the use of `<var>` other than just making the text italic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how W3Schools defines HTML:

- HTML stands for Hyper Text Markup Language
- HTML is the standard markup language for creating Web pages
- HTML describes the structure of a Web page
- HTML consists of a series of elements
- HTML elements tell the browser how to display the content
- HTML elements label pieces of content such as "this is a heading", "this is a paragraph", "this is a link", etc.

The way I see it is that, even though `<var>` and `<i>` have the same output printed to the browser, they mean different things, specially if you are "reading" pages without opening a browser like search engines do.

Check it is not particular to the example you mentioned. Look at the example on `<b>` and `<strong>` (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp). They also have the same output but mean different things.

Comment: So it's just about the meaning of it?

Comment: I would say so... By the way I ran into an article from freecodecamp yesterday that reminded me of your question. Here is the [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-elements-explained-what-are-html-tags/#em-element). Read the section about `<em>` tag, which is followed by `<i>` tag.

Comment: I can now say that with this answer and your article that I now see the BIG picture.  Thank you to have cleared that for me.

Answer (score 1):

Semantics.

`<p>` tags are generic paragraph elements, typically used for text.

`<var>` elements represent the [name of a variable in a mathematical expression or a programming context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/var).

If you italicize a paragraph it may resemble the default styling of the `<var>` element, but that's where the similarities end. Also, they're different to screen readers.

Here's an example using both elements and you can see that semantically, it's a paragraph of text that contains references to variables in a mathematical sense:

```html
<p>The volume of a box is <var>l</var> × <var>w</var> × <var>h</var>, where <var>l</var> represents the length, <var>w</var> the width and <var>h</var> the height of the box.</p>
```

Comment: I see your point and this is the same as reading all the descriptions out there.  Who or what exactly will use the <var> tag?  Is there a purpose higher than just representing mathematical expression?  I specially want to understand the reason behind having such tag.  If it's a variable it needs to be used somehow, no?  For instance, <p> is understandable because we can see something related to it visually but <var> I don't see where it is used. "they're different to screen readers" Elaborate please!

Comment: It really only has meaning in the proper context, for example if you're creating a page of documentation. You could, but aren't required to, use `<var>` around variables in a coding example. I might think of it being similar to the `<abbr>` abbreviation tag. You could use `<abbr>` around any mention of CSS, but you don't have to. Again it seems most likely to aid in screen readers and SEO